# how to move a jupyterlab notebook in the web interface?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

It seems like this would be trivial, but there is no obvious way.  Here is the context menu for the notebook file:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drag and drop items in the file tab on the left.

[image]

To move a file to its parent directory, drag the file to the folder icon in the directory path.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Umoko, when trying that approach I ran into the issue that the graphical interface does not support moving a file into a parent directory

Comment: @mkk I edited my answer to show how do that in graphical interface.